# How to control physics object in android?

Tags: coronasdk

In my game i used more than 1000 physics object.it will be run in iPhone and ipad.but Andorid extremely slow.please help me i searched solution in net but cant.In Runtime i am creating more than 800 physics object.i am creating lava flow so using runtime listener to create multiple object thats look like lava flow.

Comment: have you considered a particle engine like Particle Candy?  They are optimized for things like that.  Corona should be able to handle a large number of items, but code efficiency will impact performance and these engines are designed to work as efficiently as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.now its OK to control many object.but now i had another problem.when my level starts so many physics object iam used. so getting to late to load in android device.after loading the object it run perfectly but when i touch level1 its getting to much time to load another lua file.please help me.i had only in android device.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to preload all images you'll use. And when you need to delete them, just remove them from pysics with

```
physics.removeBody( target )
```

and set their alpha value to 0. So when you need them again, you can readd them to physics and set alpha to 1 again.

I think it will help your load problem, you mentioned in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating so many objects? What type of device are you testing this on? I don't think corona will handle that on device.

Comment: i am using galaxy player5.0.i want to create look like lava flow so that only i am creating many object.